# How in-app purchases are processed in a real ios application?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I added in-app purchases to my ios app on swiftui. After making a test purchase, a alert appears stating that the purchase was successful (I did not add this alert). At the same time, the method that tracks the successful state of the purchase is called only when I click on the "Ok" button on this alert.

Question: Does the real purchase have this system notification that the purchase is complete or failed? Or is it only during testing and I can add my own visual processing to immediately react to the state of the transaction without this system alert and clicking "ok" on this alert.

Comment: You might want to provide more detail about how you implemented in-app purchase. As this question is worded it is very hard to answer your question.

Comment: @jglasse I received an answer to the question, thanks for wanting to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production there's an iOS alert too and of course the same iOS delegate methods are called as well.

Asking this shows you want to thoroughly understand IAP. This is great, because getting IAP right is important. People pay attention when buying something, so slight app misbehaviour, especially during IAP, may give some of your users a bad feeling.

Good luck and welcome at StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer

Comment: @Nolit In fact you will find that the hard part is knowing when the system alert is gone so that you can put up _your_ alert.

Comment: @matt I was worried that if the user does not click "ok" on this alert and close the application, then the application will not process a successful transaction. But now I tested it with the knowledge I gained and saw that the transaction is being successfully processed even if I immediately tried to close the application. Now I can continue to work, thanks

Comment: @meaning-matters Thanks!)